# Inheritance and Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a hierachy as follows:

```
class UserProfileBase {
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FriendsGroup")]
    public int FriendsGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroup FriendsGroup { get; set; }
    //etc...
}

public class UserProfile : UserProfileBase
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        IsPublic = true;   // default value is true.
    }

    public string FamilyName { get; set; }  
    //etc...
}
```

It used to be that it would create a single table "UserProfile" and incorporate all the properties.  But I have since moved UserProfileBase into another assembly as part of a core library.  Now it is generating two tables "UserProfile" and "UserProfileBase" even though I do not ever add UserProfileBase to the DbContext.  I noticed it seems to be using the TPH method because UserProfileBase table contains properties from UserProfile and UserProfile table just has an id and discriminator column.

Again my DbContext is like:

```
class MyContext : DbContext {
      public List<UserProfile> People { get; set; }
}
```

I don't get it.  Is it because it is in another assembly?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using any `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(s)` involving `UserProfile`?

Comment: I found out it is because of the ForeignKey attribute in the base class.  Before it was moved into another assembly it didn't have it, now it does, and if removed it results in just the UserProfile table as expected.  I am now trying to figure out how to use fluid API to make the foreign key rather than use the attribute, maybe that will work out for me...

Comment: Yeah it seems to have worked.  I got my foreign key relationship, my navigation property, and one table that has all the properties.  Yay!

Comment: You should post an answer to this with what solved your problem and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the ForeignKey attribute in the base class.  The attribute would work if it was in the derived class, just not the base.

Therefore to keep the same functionality, I just defined the foreign key using the fluid API and took it out of the base class.